# Having problems following links with webcrawler

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a webcrawler that parses all the html on the page, grabs a specified (via `raw_input`) link, follows that link, and then repeats this process a specified number of times (once again via `raw_input`). I am able to grab the first link and successfully print it. However, I am having problems "looping" the whole process, and usually grab the wrong link. This is the first link

https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Fikret.html

(Full disclosure, this questions pertains to an assignment for a Coursera course)

Here's my code

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
url = raw_input('Enter - ')
rpt=raw_input('Enter Position')
rpt=int(rpt)
cnt=raw_input('Enter Count')
cnt=int(cnt)
count=0
counts=0
tags=list()
soup=None
while x==0:
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
    tags=soup.findAll('a')
    for tag in tags:
        url= tag.get('href')
        count=count + 1
        if count== rpt:
            break
counts=counts + 1
if counts==cnt:        
    x==1       
else: continue
print  url
```

Comment: I'm not completely understanding the input. The url is pretty clear. But why is the position and count for? In addition why would you want to redo the entire process multiple times? Don't you just need to grab all the urls on the page? Normally you just need to load the page once and get all the a tags. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I want the webcrawler to grab the a link on the webpage, for example if the user inputs the "position" as 3, and the "count" as 4 it would grab the third link, then input that link into urllib, parse that link, grab the third link on that page, and loop 4 times as specified in the "count" input.

Comment: But then you don't need to load the page 4 times, right? You could just store the parsed links as a list and only use the ones that are specified by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import *
url = raw_input('Enter - ')
position=int(raw_input('Enter Position'))
count=int(raw_input('Enter Count'))

#perform the loop "count" times.
for _ in xrange(0,count):
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    tags=soup.findAll('a')
    for tag in tags:
        url= tag.get('href')
        tags=soup.findAll('a')
        # if the link does not exist at that position, show error.
        if not tags[position-1]:
            print "A link does not exist at that position."
        # if the link at that position exist, overwrite it so the next search will use it.
        url = tags[position-1].get('href')
print url
```

The code will now loop the amount of times as specified in the input, each time it will take the href at the given position and replace it with the url, in that way each loop will look further in the *tree structure*.

I advice you to use full names for variables, which is a lot easier to understand. In addition you could cast them and read them in a single line, which makes your beginning easier to follow.

Comment: I appreciate the you taking the time to try to help me, but this isn't what I'm looking for. This adds the links to a list and then prints some of these specified links. What I'm looking to do is use one of the links on the page as a jumping off point as sorts. So the crawler would take one of the links via `tag.get('href')`, reinsert it into the file opener `urllib.urlopen(url).read`, and then parse that page, grab a link, reinsert that one into the file opener, and repeat this a specified number of times. Not sure if I made that clearer, sorry if I'm not making sense.

Comment: Aha got it, still I'm a little puzzled about the parameters. So the position says which link on the page should be returned and the count indicates how many times the process should be repeated, each time going deeper in the url tree and taking the 3the branch?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good way to explain it. I realized in the original code however, that there's no way for the internal loop to break after the first iteration because count will always be greater than the user specified number after the first iteration. However, even with the internal loop fixed, the outer loop won't break

Comment: I believe the updated code is more what you are looking for then.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. Your code was much cleaner than mine haha!

Comment: Well, I hope you learned a bit from it and perhaps try to write it yourself instead of copy and pasting it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on DJanssens' response, I found the solution;

```
url = tags[position-1].get('href')
```

did the trick for me!

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I also worked on that course, and help with a friend, I got this worked out:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Happy.html"
rpt=7
position=18

count=0
counts=0
tags=list()
soup=None
x=0
while x==0:
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    tags=soup.findAll('a')
    url= tags[position-1].get('href')
    count=count + 1
    if count == rpt:
        break

print  url
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 2-cents:

```
import urllib
#import ssl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html'
url = raw_input('Enter URL : ')
position = int(raw_input('Enter position : '))
count = int(raw_input('Enter count : '))

print('Retrieving: ' + url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url).read())

for x in range(1, count + 1):
    link = list()
    for tag in soup('a'):
        link.append(tag.get('href', None))    
    print('Retrieving: ' + link[position - 1])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(link[position - 1]).read())
```

Comment: An even more efficient answer appears here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267954/following-links-in-python-assignment-using-beautifulsoup/46653848#46653848